# Could gdrive compromise password?

Tags: windows, security, google-drive

I was looking for ways to automate uploads to my Google Drive and came across this app called Gdrive for Windows.

It's an exe that you first need to run to authorize Google Drive to generate an auth token or something similar and then with that token the command line utility accepts commands to upload your files to your Google drive. As such you do not separately enter logon credentials anywhere in your script.

I understand that anyone having access to that token can then be in a position to access my Google drive.

What I am concerned is that I guess this is a third party tool. (I am not too sure if this is released by Google or independently developed)  Would this in process of generating token in anyway compromise my google account password?

Google warns me that I should proceed only if I trust the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application doesn't receive your password but an [oAuth access token](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/). What can be done by the token is limited to the scope of the access token. Generating the token cannot compromise your Google account password, assuming the oAuth dance is done to the correct Google URL, not to a phished one